# A formula that returns a cell value using the data (number) of a cell in a specific column as the row number in another column

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

| number data | data | result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | q | q |
| 4 | w | r |
| 2 | e | w |
| 3 | r | e |
| 5 | t | t |

[image]

I want to use the number in a cell in column A as the row number in column B and return that value in column C. 
 I was hoping this formula would work. But it failed..
`=ARRAYFORMULA(INDEX(A:A,index(B:B)))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `MAP()` or `BYROW()` function. Try-

```
=MAP(A2:A6,LAMBDA(x,INDEX(B2:B,x)))
```

To make input column dynamic, use-

```
=MAP(A2:INDEX(A2:A,COUNTA(A2:A)),LAMBDA(x,INDEX(B2:B,x)))
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can try:

```
=INDEX(XLOOKUP(A:A,SEQUENCE(ROWS(A:A)),B:B,))
```

- 

[image]